# upload with multiple image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using this source: http://opoloo.github.io/jquery_upload_preview/
until now, I can upload one image with preview.

```
<style type="text/css">
.image-preview {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ecf0f1;
}
input[type="file"] {
    line-height: 200px;
    font-size: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 10;
}
  label {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
    opacity: 0.7;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: #bdc3c7;
    width: 200px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
  }

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("image-preview").each(
        function(){
                $.uploadPreview({
                    input_field: $(this).find(".image-upload"),
                    preview_box: this,
                    label_field: $(this).find(".image-label")
                });
        }
    );
});
</script>
<!--| catatan penting: yang penting action="" & input type="file" name="image" |-->
<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="image-preview">
        <label for="image-upload" class="image-label">+ GAMBAR</label>
        <input type="file" name="my_field[]" class="image-upload" />
    </div>
    <div class="image-preview">
        <label for="image-upload" class="image-label">+ GAMBAR</label>
        <input type="file" name="my_field[]" class="image-upload" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

then try to add more div class image preview, i want add another button with image preview. **i don't want multiple upload with one button.**

`$(document).ready(function() {$.uploadPreview` => use id, of course when change to class and add more div, when upload a button, another button will change. i am confused with the logic. Anyone can help? maybe using array but, i don't know how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since upload button is dependent on state of uploadPreview you need to initialize for each div separately to get separate upload buttons.
Change your html like this give each container a class say imgBox

```
<div class="imgBox">
 <label for="image-upload" class="image-label">Choose File</label>
 <input type="file" name="image" class="image-upload" />
</div>
.....
....
...
<div class="imgBox">
 <label for="image-upload" class="image-label">Choose File</label>
 <input type="file" name="image" class="image-upload" />
</div>
```

..
Now initialize each one using jquery `each()`

```
 $(".imgBox").each(
            function(){
                $.uploadPreview({
                input_field: $(this).find(".image-upload"),
                preview_box: this,
                label_field: $(this).find(".image-label")
            });
});
```

Comment: i try it and still not work. you can look my code above, i edit it.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple image uploading index.html file for image uploading and preview.

Needs j-query.No need of extra plugins.
If you have any questions ask me ;)

//to preview image you need only these lines of code

```
var imageId=idOfClicked;
var output = document.getElementById(imageId);
output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

Check it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/chs3s0jk/6/

Comment: i like that code. but in my code, i am combine with file: class.upload.php
usually using: form action and name for: input type="file". in your code i just look 1 <input type="file"> it doesn't have name. how to get file upload and processing to storage

Answer (score 0):

I have one better option for the file upload it's easy to use and you can try it.

```
window.onload = function(){   
    if(window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader){
        $(document).on("change",'.file', function(event) {
            var files = event.target.files; //FileList object
            var output = document.getElementById("upload-preview");
            $("#upload-preview").html("");
            if(files.length>5){
                $(".file").after("<div class='alert alert-error'><span class='close'></span>Maximum 5 files can be uploaded.</div>");
                $(this).val("");
                return false;
            }
            else{
                $(".file").next(".alert").remove();
            }
            for(var i = 0; i< files.length; i++)
            {
                var file = files[i];
                //Only pics 
                // if(!file.type.match('image'))
                if(file.type.match('image.*')){
                    if(this.files[0].size < 2097152){    
                  // continue;
                    var picReader = new FileReader();
                    picReader.addEventListener("load",function(event){
                        var picFile = event.target;
                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.className = "upload-preview-thumb";
                        div.style.backgroundImage = 'url('+picFile.result+')';
                        output.insertBefore(div,null);            
                    });
                    //Read the image
                    $('#clear, #upload-preview').show();
                    picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
                    }else{
                        alert("Image Size is too big. Minimum size is 1MB.");
                        $(this).val("");
                    }
                }else{
                alert("You can only upload image file.");
                $(this).val("");
            }
            }
        });
        $(".file2").change(function(event){
            var err=0;
            var input = $(event.currentTarget);
            var ele = $(this);
            var file = input[0].files[0];
            var u = URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]);

            var w = ele.attr("data-width");
            var h = ele.attr("data-height");
            var img = new Image;

            img.onload = function(){
                if(w){
                    if(img.width!=w || img.height!=h){
                        ele.parent().find(".alert").remove();
                        ele.parent().find(".upload-preview").before("<div class='alert alert-error'>Please upload a image with specified dimensions.</div>");
                        ele.val("");
                    }
                    else{
                        ele.parent().find(".alert").remove();
                    }
                }
            };

            img.src = u;

            var nh;
            if($(this).attr('data-preview')=='full')
                nh = (h/w*150)
            else
                nh=150

            var preview = ele.parent().find(".upload-preview");
            var reader = new FileReader();
            preview.show();
            reader.onload = function(e){
                image_base64 = e.target.result;
                preview.html("<div class='upload-preview-thumb' style='height:"+nh+"px;background-image:url("+image_base64+")'/><div>");
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
        });

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Your browser does not support File API");
    }
}
```

above code save as one js file like file-upload.js 
then link it to your file where you want perview.
 i.e.

```
<script src="js/file-upload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

use this kind of example for the input type

```
<input type="file" class="file2" name="page-image" id="page-image"/>
```

that works on the class that name is "file2" that class you given to the input field that able to create preview.

full structure something like below.

**HTML Code you can try**

```
<input type="file" class="file2" name="page-image[]" id="page-image"/>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="upload-preview" style="display: block;">
    <div class="upload-preview-thumb">
    // perview genereate here
    // you can display image also here if uploaded throw the php condition in edit image part
    </div>
</div>
<input type="file" class="file2" name="page-image[]" id="page-image"/>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<div class="upload-preview" style="display: block;">
    <div class="upload-preview-thumb">
    // perview genereate here
    // you can display image also here if uploaded throw the php condition in edit image part
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.upload-preview {
  border: 1px dashed #ccc;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}
.upload-preview-thumb {
  background-position: 50% 25%;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: 139px;
}
```

Hope this works and in future it's helpful for you.

Thanks.

Comment: what should input: 
// perview genereate here
// you can display image also here if uploaded throw the php condition in edit image part

it not display custom upload button.

Comment: for now nothing put there. there is for additional thing. if you inserting image. but when you use same page for the edit then you can put there image tag if you found old data then fill that image in image tag other wise image tag not display something like that.

Comment: try class file instead of the file2. and make sure about the jquery core file attachments.

Comment: add your Image preview html exact after the input type.